# Merge multiple csv files using batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

Is it possible to merge multiple CSV files [same directory] into one using a batch file? If so, how can I do this?

I think that would apply to any ASCII file?

Comment: do those files have exactly the same column types?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same.

Comment: Take a look at [Merge / combine / copy the content of text or CSV files into a new file](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=7118) for an UltraEdit scripting solution. I have written there also why I'm using the script and do not use command `copy`.

Comment: Are you *really* using DOS? or do you mean command prompt in Windows??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
copy *.csv merged.csv
```

or

```
copy file1+file2+… merged.csv
```

for a more sophisticated script that avoids duplicate headers, see [Batch Combine CSV Remove Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745623/batch-combine-csv-remove-header)

Comment: if the CSV has column names in first row this will get duplicated in merged.csv. no big deal if the output is meant for manual processing but may get some errors if it is not handled properly

Comment: @rostok this page (option 2) has the solution to the problem: https://www.itsupportguides.com/office-2010/how-to-merge-multiple-csv-files-into-one-csv-file-using-cmd/

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want to know what line came from which file. 
If you just use

copy *.csv merged.csv

you will get the files pasted one after the other, with no way to know which line came from which file.

A solution involves use of grep.exe utility. You can get it from places such as this one: 
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

Once you have it (and add its location to your PATH), go to the folder where the csv files are and run this in a command shell:

grep  -e ^a*$ *.csv > t.txt

The result will be that all the files are added to t.txt, with the filename appended at the beginning of each line, separated by ":" from the file's text.

Example:

**file1.csv**

this,line

is,from

file,1

**file2.csv**

this,line

is,from

file,2

after you run the grep command, t.txt will have:

file1.csv:this,line

file1.csv:is,from

file1.csv:file,1

file2.csv:this,line

file2.csv:is,from

file2.csv:file,2

Change t.txt .t.csv, and open in Excel. 
The next step is to take the first column and split it to two column, using ":" as a delimiter (Data -> text to columns -> delimited and select "other" and put ":" in the field.  )

Careful! add a new column between column A and B, so that when column A is split into 2 columns, it does not overwrite the contents of column B.

Note that if the text in the first csv field contains ":", this will be a bit more difficult as column A will split into more than 2 columns.

Also, the comments about duplicate headers hold here as well.

Answer (score 0):

For TEXT Files

```
DEL c:\CombineFiles\CombinedFiles.txt

@echo off>CombinedFiles.txt
for /r  %%a in (.) do copy/b CombinedFiles.txt+"%%a\*.txt" c:\CombineFiles\CombinedFiles.txt
```

For CSV Files

```
DEL c:\CombineFiles\CombinedFiles.csv

@echo off>CombinedFiles.csv
for /r  %%a in (.) do copy/b CombinedFiles.csv+"%%a\*.csv" c:\CombineFiles\CombinedFiles.csv
```

For CSV to TXT files

```
DEL c:\CombineFiles\CombinedFiles.txt

@echo off>CombinedFiles.csv
for /r  %%a in (.) do copy/b CombinedFiles.csv+"%%a\*.csv" c:\CombineFiles\CombinedFiles.txt
```