# How to merge multiple csv files which are under different subfolders into a single csv file?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have a zip folder, under that I have many sub folders and each sub folder has some csv files. Now i want to copy (merge) all the csv files from different sub folders into one csv file... by using only batch scripting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge multiple csv files using batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596171/merge-multiple-csv-files-using-batch-file)

Comment: @Prasad, use Google or other search site before asking. I see several solutions for this query: [windows merge multiple csv batch file](https://www.google.com/#q=windows+merge+multiple+csv+batch+file).

Answer (score 1):

The code below searches through subdirectories with `DIR /S`  looking for .csv files. Upon finding one, it appends the contents to the file named in the SUMMARY_FILE variable.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET SUMMARY_FILE=C:\Users\bone\sumfile.csv
IF EXIST "%SUMMARY_FILE%" (DEL "%SUMMARY_FILE%")
CD C:\root\of\all\csv\files

SET /A LINE_COUNT=1

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f IN (`DIR /S /B *.csv`) DO (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%s IN (`TYPE "%%~f"`) DO (
        ECHO !LINE_COUNT!,%%s >>"%SUMMARY_FILE%"
        SET /A LINE_COUNT=!LINE_COUNT! + 1
    )
)
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: Mogsdad the solution provided by u is excellent... and now I am in need of one more requirement i.e. after this merging I need a new column saying S.No. and it should contain values starting from 1,2,3.... to number of rows

Comment: like

S.No.

1
2
3
4
5
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
n

Comment: @Prasad - I have not tested this change. Does this work for you?

Comment: @Liturgist - Actually its not working... script looks good, seems it require little bit of changes. Working on that.....

Comment: @Mogsdad - could u pls hlp me with the new requirement, which I have mentioned in above comments...Thanks in advance

Comment: @Liturgist I had to remove `TYPE` but the script works fine. I wanted it to work for files starting with the letters "EVN". But when changing the script to `EVN*.csv` nothing is happening. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Flouks - I just saw this again and it was missing a backtick on the TYPE command. I edited the answer.