# How to Merge multiple CSV files from different subfolders?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I know this is a common question but I run into some bugs and hope for some help.

I want to merge over a 1000 csv files in multiple subfolders into one file. The Script is in the `MainFolder` and should run through the subfolder e.g. `01_2015` to `05_2015` and merge the csv files into one file in the `MainFolder`.

I've got the following folder structure:

```
-MainFolder
    -01_2015
    -02_2015
    -03_2015
    -04_2015
    -05_2015
```

The script I'm using (got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995274/how-to-merge-multiple-csv-files-which-are-under-different-subfolders-into-a-sing) ):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET SUMMARY_FILE=sumfile.csv
IF EXIST "%SUMMARY_FILE%" (DEL "%SUMMARY_FILE%")


SET /A LINE_COUNT=1

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f IN (`DIR /S /B *.csv`) DO (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%s IN ("%%~f") DO (
        ECHO !LINE_COUNT!,%%s >>"%SUMMARY_FILE%"
        SET /A LINE_COUNT=!LINE_COUNT! + 1
    )
)
EXIT /B 0
```

It is actually running through the over 1000 files. But the files don't get merged. What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this slightly modified code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
PUSHD "%~dp0"

SET "SUMMARY_FILE=sumfile.csv"
DEL /F "%SUMMARY_FILE%" 2>nul

SET "LINE_COUNT=1"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('DIR /S /B *.csv 2^>nul') DO (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol=ÿ" %%s IN ("%%~f") DO (
        >>"%SUMMARY_FILE%" ECHO !LINE_COUNT!%%s
        SET /A LINE_COUNT+=1
    )
)

POPD
ENDLOCAL
```

The redirection `>>"%SUMMARY_FILE%"` is now at beginning of the line which outputs the line from current CSV file with line number into the summary file. This avoids appending a space at end of every line in summary file.

Do you have write permissions in directory which is set as current directory on running the batch file?

I added the line `PUSHD "%~dp0"` to make sure the directory of the batch file is the current directory before starting processing and restore previous working directory with `POPD` before exiting batch processing.

`eol=ÿ` is used to define a character most likely not existing in the CSV files as end of line character instead of `;` which is the default. German CSV files contain `;` as separator.

Character `ÿ` has decimal value 255 in code page [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), i.e. is the last character in code page Windows-1252. This byte is a non breaking space in OEM [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850). So with batch file being displayed or edited with code page 850 or OEM [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), `eol=`  is displayed in viewer/editor.

No separator should be used between `!LINE_COUNT!` and `%%s` if all lines start already with a semicolon in the CSV files which is also the separator between the field values. Otherwise the separator (comma, semicolon, pipe (escaped), tab) should be inserted left to `%%s`.

Another problem would be if the CSV files are Unicode files encoded with UTF-16. In this case no summary file would be created as command **FOR** reads any line from the CSV files containing lots of null bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked the csv files for their encoding (it's ANSI). Your script is running well but again... Nothing is merged. I tested it also with some random csv files from the internet. It turns out that all the csv files start with a `;` (semicolon). Viewed in excel, the first whole column is empty. I removed it from a few of my files and now the script works and they get merged.

What do I need to do, to get the script to work for files with a `;` in front (first column empty when viewed in excel)?

Comment: I edited the answer, added `eol=ÿ` to second __FOR__ loop and removed comma between `!LINE_COUNT!` and `%%s` as it looks like your CSV files use the semicolon as separator being already present at beginning of each line.

Comment: NICE! Thanks @Mofi . I wish I knew how to do it myself!
Working like a charm! :D