# How to skip two consecutive match lines

Tags: batch-file, text, command-line, skip

My target is to clean a log file from unnecessary lines, and this is my first script for Daily Statistics:

```
set CDPath=C:\ConnectDirect
set CDWin="C:\CDwin\Common Utilities\Direct"
echo sel stats startt=(8:30:00) stopt=(22:30:00) recids | %CDWin% -x > %CDPath%\report.log
```

This is a report:

```
==============================================================================
                                Select Statistics
==============================================================================
P RECID  LOG TIME            PNAME     PNUMBER STEPNAME CCOD FDBK   MSGID
E RECID  LOG TIME            MESSAGE TEXT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E SSTR   12/12/2015 12:00:37 SNODE session started - remote node target                                                        
P PSTR   12/12/2015 12:00:37 ##SNT$1N  22024            0    0      LSMG200I
P PRED   12/12/2015 12:00:37 ##SNT$1N  22024            0    0      SCPA000I
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:12 SNODE session started - remote node target                                                        
P PSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:12 ##SNT$1N  23109            0    0      LSMG200I
P PRED   12/12/2015 21:37:12 ##SNT$1N  23109            0    0      SCPA000I
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:14 SNODE session started - remote node target                                                        
P PSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:14 ##SNT$1N  23110            0    0      LSMG200I
P PRED   12/12/2015 21:37:15 ##SNT$1N  23110            0    0      SCPA000I
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:16 SNODE session started - remote node target                                                        
P PSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:16 ##SNT$1N  23111            0    0      LSMG200I
P PRED   12/12/2015 21:37:19 ##SNT$1N  23111            0    0      SCPA000I
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:19 SNODE session started - remote node target                                                        
P PSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:19 ##SNT$1N  23112            0    0      LSMG200I
P PRIN   12/12/2015 21:37:21           0                8    0      LSMI008I
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:21 PNODE session not started - remote node 00000000                                                  
P PRIN   12/12/2015 21:37:23           0                8    0      LSMI008I
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:23 PNODE session not started - remote node 00000000                                                  
P PRED   12/12/2015 21:37:24 ##SNT$1N  23112            0    0      SCPA000I
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:24 SNODE session started - remote node target                                                        
P PSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:24 ##SNT$1N  23114            0    0      LSMG200I
P PRED   12/12/2015 21:37:24 ##SNT$1N  23114            0    0      SCPA000I
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:40:23 SNODE session started - remote node target                                                        
P PSTR   12/12/2015 21:40:23 ##SNT$1N  23113            0    0      LSMG200I
P PRED   12/12/2015 21:40:25 ##SNT$1N  23113            0    0      SCPA000I
```

Now I like to create e new file removing all the lines that match this pattern " "!/PNODE session not started/ and skip the next near line

```
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:21 PNODE session not started - remote node 00000000                                                  
P PRIN   12/12/2015 21:37:23           0                8    0      LSMI008I
```

I try to use this script with awk, but works only for the first line but not for second one

```
gawk  "!/PNODE session not started/ {print; next}" Report.log > newreport.log
```

Also the second row must macth exactly this record

```
  0                8    0      LSMI008I
```

How can I remove also a second line?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You must be much clearer in your request. Add more details, more input lines and the output you want to generate with such input. You must also add the code that shown your efforts to solve this problem; this is not a free code writting service... Please, modify the question; do not post details in comments!

Comment: So in your sample file, the first occurrence of the second pattern (`0    8  0`, the one from `21:37:21`) must not be removed, but the next three lines must be removed, is that correct??

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "skip2="
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q34262715.txt) DO (
 ECHO %%a|FINDSTR /l /c:"PNODE session not started" /c:"INODE session not started" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  IF NOT DEFINED skip2 ECHO(%%a
  SET "skip2="
 ) ELSE (SET skip2=y)
)
)>u:\newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q34262715.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces u:\newfile.txt

- Reads each line of the data into `%%a`.
- checks whether the line contained either of the target strings
- If so, set `skip2`
- if not, then if `skip2` is set, the previous line matched so skip this and clear `skip2`
- otherwise, reproduce the line

Answer (score 0):

Another batch solution for this task which is faster than code written by [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34268660/3074564) because of not using `findstr` which is very slow.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Skip=0"
(
    for /F "usebackq eol=ÿ delims=" %%L in ("%CDPath%\report.log") do (
        if "!Skip!" == "1" (
            set "Skip=0"
        ) else (
            set "Line=%%L"
            if "!Line:PNODE session not started=!" == "!Line!" (
                echo %%L
            ) else (
                set "Skip=1"
            )
        )
    )
) >"%CDPath%\FilteredReport.log"
endlocal
```

Each not empty line is read from the report file.

All lines on which variable `Skip` has not value 0 are skipped.

The line containing `PNODE session not started` case insensitive is also skipped as also next line because of assigning value 1 to variable `Skip`.

All other lines are output by command **echo** and this output is redirected to file `FilteredReport.log` in same directory as `report.log`.

`eol=ÿ` just makes sure that command **FOR** does not skip lines starting with a semicolon on reading the lines from report file.

The result for the input data example is:

```
==============================================================================
                                Select Statistics
==============================================================================
P RECID  LOG TIME            PNAME     PNUMBER STEPNAME CCOD FDBK   MSGID
E RECID  LOG TIME            MESSAGE TEXT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E SSTR   12/12/2015 12:00:37 SNODE session started - remote node target                                                        
P PSTR   12/12/2015 12:00:37 ##SNT$1N  22024            0    0      LSMG200I
P PRED   12/12/2015 12:00:37 ##SNT$1N  22024            0    0      SCPA000I
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:12 SNODE session started - remote node target                                                        
P PSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:12 ##SNT$1N  23109            0    0      LSMG200I
P PRED   12/12/2015 21:37:12 ##SNT$1N  23109            0    0      SCPA000I
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:14 SNODE session started - remote node target                                                        
P PSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:14 ##SNT$1N  23110            0    0      LSMG200I
P PRED   12/12/2015 21:37:15 ##SNT$1N  23110            0    0      SCPA000I
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:16 SNODE session started - remote node target                                                        
P PSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:16 ##SNT$1N  23111            0    0      LSMG200I
P PRED   12/12/2015 21:37:19 ##SNT$1N  23111            0    0      SCPA000I
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:19 SNODE session started - remote node target                                                        
P PSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:19 ##SNT$1N  23112            0    0      LSMG200I
P PRIN   12/12/2015 21:37:21           0                8    0      LSMI008I
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:24 SNODE session started - remote node target                                                        
P PSTR   12/12/2015 21:37:24 ##SNT$1N  23114            0    0      LSMG200I
P PRED   12/12/2015 21:37:24 ##SNT$1N  23114            0    0      SCPA000I
E SSTR   12/12/2015 21:40:23 SNODE session started - remote node target                                                        
P PSTR   12/12/2015 21:40:23 ##SNT$1N  23113            0    0      LSMG200I
P PRED   12/12/2015 21:40:25 ##SNT$1N  23113            0    0      SCPA000I
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `echo /?`

Comment: Sorry chars ÿ after eol= is not recognized

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The goal of `eol=ÿ` is just to replace default `eol=;`. Any other character surely not existing in report file can be used, too. For details on how `eol=ÿ` is displayed in text editor depending on used code page see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34155288/3074564). You hopefully do not save your batch file as Unicode file (UTF-8, UTF-16) as this would be indeed a problem. Best is using code page in editor as used by Windows for console. Run `chcp` in a command prompt window to get information about default code page on your machine.

Comment: I don't try to help anymore as long as you negate the Stack Overflow rules and post answers which are not answers and as long as you don't know what you want and make this clear in question. Stack Overflow is not a forum!

Comment: Sorry this is my first post, I promise to read more carefully Stack Overflow rules, thanks again for support

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this and it seems works fine

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Skip=0"
(
    for /F "usebackq eol= delims=" %%L in ("D:\report_inp.log") do (
        if "!Skip!" == "1" (
            set "Skip=0"
        ) else (
            set "Line=%%L"
            if "!Line:          0                8    0      LSMI008I=!" == "!Line!" (
                    if "!Line:PNODE session not started - remote node=!" == "!Line!" (
                echo %%L
                )
            ) else (
                set "Skip=1"
            )
        )
    )
) >"D:\Report_Out.log"
endlocal
```

Problem solved, thank to all for support!

Comment: Note that you defined the _SPACE_ to be the `eol` character in the `for /F` options; `eol=` _always_ takes the following character, even if you write `"usebackq eol=delims="` (meaning `d` is taken and `elims=` is not understood, so an error is thrown) or `"usebackq delims= eol="` (meaning `"` is taken, but no error is thrown); you could either define a character that does never occur first in the text file, or you use the strange looking undocumented _unquoted_ syntax `usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^=`