# Merge multiple csv created last week

Tags: csv, batch-file, merge, batch-processing

This script provided by [raccoozie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19592600/3664960) works as described:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set first=1
set fileName="combinedFiles.csv"
>%fileName% (
  for %%F in (*.csv) do (
    if not "%%F"==%fileName% (
      if defined first (
        type "%%F"
        set "first="
      ) else more +1 "%%F"
    )
  )
)
```

Now I want to add a criteria to only select the files created from the last 7 days.

The problem is that the program doesn't create 1 file daily, but could create 7, 5, 9 or 0 files at certain days.

How to start?

Answer (score 1):

To merge the **7** last created *.csv* :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a $c=1
set "fileName=combinedFiles.csv"

>"%filename%" (for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir/b/a-d/od *.csv') do (
  if not "%%F"=="%fileName%" if !$c! LEQ 7 (
  type "%%F"
  set /a $c+=1)
  ))
```

**EDIT :** To merge all *.csv* files created the last 7 days and sorted by date

```
@Echo off
::Get current Date -7 days with VBS
echo wscript.echo DateAdd("d", -7, date(^)^) >GetDate.vbs
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo GetDate.vbs') do set "$Limit=%%a"
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ('echo %$Limit%') do set /a $Limit=%%c%%b%%a
Del GetDate.vbs 2>nul

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "fileName=combinedFiles.csv"

(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir/b/a-d/o-d "*.csv"') do (
     for /f "tokens=1-3* delims=/ " %%b in ('dir /TC "%%a" ^| find "/"') do set "$DateTest=%%d%%c%%b"
     if not "%%F"=="%fileName%" if !$DateTest! GEQ %$Limit% type "%%a"
)
)>%fileName%"
```

The date is transformed 11/02/2016 come 20160211 to have logic testing value
(A later date will always be greater). So we can test all sorting (by `dir /o-d`) files for a value greater as `$Limit`.

Now we have the files sorted by date and not older than 7 days.

Comment: didn't work, it deleted my existing csv file, but didn't create a new one. If I look at the code it looks like you go to a specific directory. Please assume I run the `.bat` file within the directory where the files reside.

Comment: Sorry i forgot  a closing bracket and two double quote test-it again

Comment: oke, now it works, takes 7 files, but takes the first created (by date) I need the last created by date. If possible it could be more then 7 files but take the files created in the last 7 days. already +1 for solution

Comment: Try with `dir/b/a-d/o-d` instead of `dir/b/a-d/od` to reverse the order

Comment: Check my Edit. Using forfiles to merge all csv files created the last 7 days

Comment: the edited version isn't sorted by date desc, where can I change that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103243/discussion-between-davejal-and-sachadee).

Comment: I tried it and it seems to work, but because the data is to big I tried to lower the 7 to 3, but it keeps processing the same amount of files.

Comment: I think I found the error but can't fix it. I made the bat echo the process and I noticed I searching for 2016102, where it should be searching for 20160210.

Comment: The date are inverted ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET "filename1=alreadydone.txt"
IF NOT EXIST "%filename1%" ECHO x:>>"%filename1%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d /o:d "*.csv" ^|findstr /x /v /g:"%filename1%'
 ) DO (
 rem do your combine-file [%%a] here
 ECHO %%a>>"%filename1%"
)
```

This part-routine (generating `%%a` instead of `%%F` because that's what my template does) takes the directory list and excludes files in `filename1`. The remaining files are delivered to the combine-file section of the code you've already produced, and the filename is recorded in `filename1`.

The `if not exist` line generates a dummy entry in `filename1` so that `findstr` does not complain the file is empty.

With this scheme, once any file has been processed, its name is saved in `filename1` and it won't be re-processed. Only new files will be combined using your combination code.

Result: No anchor about "7" or any other number of days. If you run it 7 days apart, those 7 days' processing will be combined and recorded. If you do it 5 days apart in anticipation of a public holiday, it will combine those 5 days. If you go on vacation for 2 weeks, then since no-one will follow your instruction to run it, it will combine the last 14 days. Or you could run it every day...

---

So here's the combined batch

```
@echo off
setlocal
set first=1
set fileName="combinedFiles.csv"
SET "filename1=alreadydone.txt"
IF NOT EXIST "%filename1%" ECHO x:>>"%filename1%"
>%fileName% (
for /f %%F in ('dir /b /a-d /o:d "*.csv" ^|findstr /x /v /g:"%filename1%"'
) do (
 ECHO %%F>>"%filename1%"
    if not "%%F"==%fileName% (
      if defined first (
        type "%%F"
        set "first="
      ) else more +1 "%%F"
    )
  )
)
```

[Edit:] removed `sourcedir` in `for/f` because no directory-specification is required (files are in current directory)

[Further edit:] re-add `/f` in `for` and add missing closing-rabbit's ears.

Comment: I like the explanation, but this doesn't create the merged file

Comment: I got the following error `The system cannot find the file specified.` If I uncomment the echo and run it in prompt

Comment: in the already done file I get the following

 x:
'dir
/b
/a-d
/o:d
|findstr
/x
/v
/g:"alreadydone.txt'
'dir
/b
/a-d
/o:d
|findstr
/x
/v
/g:"alreadydone.txt'
'dir
/b
/a-d
/o:d
|findstr
/x
/v
/g:"alreadydone.txt'